# make android AsynTask to wait for result

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

i want to implement a login activity. it checks user existance with a webservice.

```
        EditText un=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        EditText pass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPass);
        WS ss=new WS();
        String str=ss.execute("checkLogin",un.getText().toString(),pass.getText().toString()).get();
        Intent in=new Intent(arg0.getContext(), Overview.class);
        in.putExtra("username", str);
        if(str=="No User")
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ss", 300).show();
        else
        {
            startActivity(in);
            finish();
        }
```

the problem is in "IF" section. "str" value sets after finishing code lines.
but i want to get "str" value then check for IF to run proper actions.

Comment: Place that code in `onPostExecute` method of the `AsyncTask` class.

Comment: WS class is in a seprate file. How can i start an activity from postExecute of the asyncTask class or change value of a edittext? Is it possible?

Comment: To update the UI, make your WS class an inner class instead of creating it in a new file. This way you'll be able to access the public variables of the outer class that extends fragment or AppCompatActivity.

Comment: I want to check if information is true let userbsee overview activity... but i cant start new activity from that asyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

You need override onPostExecute method see below example

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
  protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
      int count = urls.length;
      long totalSize = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
          publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
      }
      return totalSize;
  }

  protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
      setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
      showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
  }
}
```

Comment: I know use of Toast.maketext or some funcs like this but i want to be able to act like when i'm coding in an activity class. Foe example start an activity

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of an asynchronous task is to not block synchronously. You have several options if you do want synchronous behavior:

- Don't use AsyncTask in the first place (probably not a good idea if it is a long-running network call)
- Put the code you want to run after the AsyncTask completes it's background work in the `onPostExecute` method, which will have access to the result of the data returned from the background method
- Provide a callback to the AsyncTask that `onPostExecute` can call when it is finished (similar in concept to the previous option but more formal and robust to changes)

I prefer the last option, but it also takes more dev time to write than the other options.

Don't forget that an AsyncTask may do it's background work and/or finish after the activity has been finished and shut down, so make sure to check for that state appropriately before you start interacting with the UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do a network call you shouldn't use asynctask rather use loopj or google's volley library .

Asynctask is not meant for long network calls , having said that here's an example of asynctask class , **code:**

```
    class AsyncTaskExample extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> { 
    private  final String TAG = AsyncTaskExample.class.getName(); 
    protected void onPreExecute(){
    Log.d(TAG, "On preExceute...");
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void...arg0) {

        Log.d(TAG, "On doInBackground...");

        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
            Integer in = new Integer(i);
            publishProgress(i);
        }

        return "You are at PostExecute";}

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...a){
        Log.d(TAG,"You are in progress update ... " + a[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d(TAG,result); 
        }
    }
```

Edit it as you wish and instanciate a new one in your code when you want to do the check up , 
Hope it helps